# How to force Spotlight to index only certain volumes with no new volume indexing?

Tags: macos, spotlight

I need to force Spotlight to index only two volumes and to never try to index future inserted or attached volumes again, including networked volumes. In this case I want to index `/` and `/Volumes/Users` and to exclude every other volume no matter what from now and forever.

How can I do this?

Comment: I'm trying to pick apart the three different questions here. 1. Disable all attached indexing. 2. Disable network indexing (and I'm curious how you see that happening - might need a detailed Q on that alone). 3. Enable two when attach is disabled. Why wouldn't each of these be a little more detailed question and when you get answers to each - maybe ask how to harmonize the individual solutions?

Comment: Is the network NFS? https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/43653/5472

Comment: Opting out on local drives? https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/3319/spotlight-dont-index-a-volume

Comment: In this case I have about 10 volumes attached to my computer. 6 are local, 4 are SMB auto-attached at boot. I only want 2 of the volumes ever to be indexed by Spotlight: `/` and `/Volumes/Users`. I attach new customer volumes every couple days and don't want Spotlight to start ripping through them, etc. Same with SMB connected volumes where also new ones pop up at least once a week.

Comment: Has your server admin team evaluated deploying /Volumes/whatever/.metadata_never_index files and providing indexing services centrally rather than having every client see the files as local?

Comment: I am the server admin team, so I appreciate the suggestion. :D Do you have some pointers / tips / links that might point my horse north?

Comment: I suppose I don’t get what you mean by networked volumes - I typically get from the vendor of your sharing software like https://www.synology.com/en-us/knowledgebase/DSM/help/DSM/AdminCenter/file_winmacnfs_mac Symbology manages it for you with their search. Acronis Access Connect also manages it. I suppose it depends on the details of how you’re setting up the SMB / AFP / whatever shares you run.

Comment: Just using integrated functionality for macOS and Windows on these shares, no NAS involved.